# IndexError: list index out of range when using UpdateCursor

Tags: arcgis-pro, cursor, update

I am trying to update all values in column in a feature layer in ArcGIS Pro using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor, but I am getting the error:
IndexError: list index out of range

I am trying to update all current values in the column "Dist_Next" with the values in the list distance_next_stop, i.e. the first row should be replaced with 19.32..., the second row with 73.84..., etc. The feature layer and the list contains the same amount of rows. What am I doing wrong here?

```
distance_next_stop = [19.320592048800002, 73.8492150239, 162.16051086800002, 0.361037751915, 162.295311589, 0]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("out_stops", "Dist_Next") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row = distance_next_stop[i]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The column "Dist_Next" in the feature layer "out_stops" that I want to update:

[image: The column "Dist_Next" in the feature layer "out_stops" that I want to update]

Comment: Your code doesn't declare or alter `i`. Try putting parens or braces around `row`, since a list is expected in the updateCursor method. Note that it isn't safe to assume that rows will always be processed in physical order.

Comment: In a specific line, or using (row) or {row} in line 3, 4, and 5?

Comment: Regarding declaring and altering, does that mean doing something like:

for row in cursor:
        i = 0
        row = distance_next_stop[i]
        i += 1
        cursor.updateRow(row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
import arcpy

distance_next_stop = [19.320592048800002, 73.8492150239, 162.16051086800002, 0.361037751915, 162.295311589, 0]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("out_stops", "Dist_Next") as cursor:
    for row, dist in zip(cursor, distance_next_stop):
        row[0] = dist
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Or [enumerate:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
...
for i, row in enumerate(cursor):
    row[0] = distance_next_stop[i]
...
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick - much appreciated!

Comment: Nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox